# Issue with Fabric settings()

Tags: python, fabric

Running the latest version of Fabric (1.11.1) (Paramiko (1.16.0), Python (2.7.11)) and im getting the strangest error, i did a little proof of concept to try it out.

```
from fabric.api import run, sudo, task
from fabric.context_managers import settings


@task
def test():
    print('regular run')
    run('whoami')

    print('regular sudo')
    sudo('whoami')

    print('sudo with user arg')
    sudo('whoami', user='www-data')

    with settings(user='www-data'):
        print('run inside settings')
        run('whoami')
```

output:

```
$ fab -f test.py -H vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222 test
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] Executing task 'test'
regular run
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] run: whoami
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] out: vagrant        # <--- good
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] out: 

regular sudo
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] sudo: whoami
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] out: root           # <--- good
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] out: 

sudo with user arg
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] sudo: whoami
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] out: www-data       # <--- good
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] out: 

run inside settings
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] run: whoami
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] out: vagrant        # <--- WHAT THE HECK!? this used to work
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] out: 


Done.
```

Did something change? Or i'm i just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another Fabric issue, turns out if you do cute things like: `-H vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222` internally it doesn't break it down to what you would expect: `env.user = 'vagrant'; env.host = '127.0.0.1'; env.port = '2222'` but it just keeps it in the `host_string`. <strike>So... ugh, here is the ugliest hack in the world:</strike>

```
from fabric.api import run, sudo, task, env
from fabric.context_managers import settings as _settings


def settings(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    Helper function because Fabric's setting() is broken

    Checks to see if there is a '@' in the host_string and if there is, it 
    will then append it to the host_string since that will be how it changes 
    users. Otherwise if the host_string is not being used, it will use the 
    default "swap user" functionality
    """
    if 'user' in kwargs and '@' in env.host_string:
        kwargs['host_string'] = '{}@{}'.format(
            kwargs.pop('user'),
            env.host_string.split('@')[1]
        )
    return _settings(*args, **kwargs)


@task
def test():
    print('regular run')
    run('whoami')
    print('regular sudo')
    sudo('whoami')

    print('sudo with user arg')
    sudo('whoami', user='www-data')
    with settings(user='www-data'):
        print('run inside settings')
        run('whoami')
```

This helps with keeping the code fairly "clean" and not having a bunch of `with settings(host_string='www-data@' + env.host_string.split('@')[1]):` all over the place, only to realize they break if you define the fabric command like: `fab .. --user=vagrant --host=127.0.0.1 --port=2222`. This solution works with the following:

`fab -f test.py --user=vagrant --host=127.0.0.1 --port=2222 test`

`fab -f test.py -H vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222 test`

---

*Old solution*

```
from fabric.api import run, sudo, task, env
from fabric.context_managers import settings


@task
def test():
    print('regular run')
    run('whoami')
    print('regular sudo')
    sudo('whoami')

    print('sudo with user arg')
    sudo('whoami', user='www-data')
    with settings(host_string='www-data@' + env.host_string.split('@')[1]):
        print('run inside settings')
        run('whoami')
```

output:

```
$ fab -f test.py -H vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222 test
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] Executing task 'test'
regular run
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] run: whoami
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] out: vagrant        # <--- good
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] out: 

regular sudo
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] sudo: whoami
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] out: root           # <--- good
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] out: 

sudo with user arg
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] sudo: whoami
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] out: www-data       # <--- good
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] out: 

run inside settings
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] run: whoami
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] out: www-data       # <--- good
[vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222] out: 


Done.
```

***If anyone knows a good work around for this, please let me know, im all ears!***